# JavaFX development with just JavaScript (Nashorn)

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, nashorn

Is there a way to write a JavaFX app with just JavaScript files now that Nashorn is available in Java 8? Where can I find more info or videos on this? How would you compile it?

Or is there a minimal set of bootstrapping files required?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can develop JavaFX programs with just JavaScript (Nashorn).

**How to access JavaFX from JavaScript**

Use the `jjs -fx yourscript.js` command line switch.

The `-fx` flag on [`jjs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jjs.html) will bootstrap scripts using a [`javafx.application.Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

There is no compile step for JavaScript, just write your script and run it with `jjs -fx`.

There are no bootstrapping files required.

The `jjs` binary and the JavaFX runtime are both shipped with the Oracle Java 8 Runtime Environment (JRE) and `jjs` is located in the bin directory of the JRE installation.

**Sample Code**

A Hello World example (copied from [Jim Laskey's blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/jjs_fx)).

```
var Button    = Java.type("javafx.scene.control.Button");
var StackPane = Java.type("javafx.scene.layout.StackPane");
var Scene     = Java.type("javafx.scene.Scene");

$STAGE.title = "Hello World!";
var button = new Button();
button.text = "Say 'Hello World'";
button.onAction = function() print("Hello World!");
var root = new StackPane();
root.children.add(button);
$STAGE.scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
$STAGE.show();
```

**Additional Resources**

There are numerous web examples of running JavaFX using Nashorn scripts.

1. [JavaFX with Nashorn Hello World and 3D demos](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/javaone_a_year_makes_a)
2. [JavaFX with Nashorn Canvas example](http://justmy2bits.com/2013/09/08/javafx-with-nashorn-canvas-example/).
3. [JavaFX with Nashorn Animated Gauge Demo](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.de/2013/06/taming-nashornagain.html).
4. [JavaFX with Nashorn LED readout demo](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/repost_taming_the_nashorn_first).

Comment: Cay Horstmann's "Java 8 for the really impatient" has some interesting discussion of this too.