# How to execute a javascript without webview or fxml in a JavaFX Application?

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-8

I've got a JavaFX sample code, with a CSS file and javascript file, without html code and without fxml code, and I want to load the javascript file code.
I know how to load the css file with:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(Login.class.getResource("login.css").toExternalForm());
```

But I don't find a same instruction for a javascript file. I want to add the javascript file code to the scene:

The .java code is:

```
package login;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Login extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bienvenido a JavaFX");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Login.class.getResource("login.css").toExternalForm());


        Text scenetitle = new Text("Bienvenido");
        //scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        scenetitle.setId("welcome-text");
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Label userName = new Label("Nombre de Usuario:");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

        TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

        Label pw = new Label("Contraseña:");
        grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

        PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);

        //grid.setGridLinesVisible(true); // Para Debugging.

        Button btn = new Button("Entrar");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

        //Eventos(btn, actiontarget);

        primaryStage.show();
    }
    // I WANT TO SUBSTITUTE THIS  EVENT WITH THE JAVASCRIPT FILE CODE 
    /*public void Eventos(Button btn, final Text actiontarget) {
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            //actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
            actiontarget.setId("actiontarget");
            actiontarget.setText("Botón Entrar presionado");
        });
    }*/

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The javascript code is: ***login.js***

```
var actiontarget = document.getElementById("actiontarget") ;
function handleSubmitButtonAction() {
    actiontarget.setText("Calling the JavaScript");
}
```

The css code is: ***login.css***

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 0.750em;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-text-fill: #333333;
}
.label, #actiontarget {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#welcome-text {
    -fx-font-size: 2.0em;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
    -fx-fill: #818181;
    -fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 6, 0.0, 0, 2);
}
#actiontarget {
    -fx-fill: firebrick;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Narrow";
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#61a2b1, #2A5058);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
    -fx-transition: all 2s linear;
}
.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#2A5058, #61a2b1);
}
```

I know how to make it with a FXML file, and all the possible solutions that i've found from internet are using webview, webengine and an html file, but i don't have an html file in my application.

**This code is from ifxpub-get_started.pdf document from the official Oracle JavaFX webpage.**

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your question, but maybe it's a duplicate of: [JavaFX development with just JavaScript (Nashorn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436894/javafx-development-with-just-javascript-nashorn)

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more about what you're trying to do, or perhaps *why* you want to execute javascript here. Also, if you don't have an HTML document, it's not clear what the `document` variable in the javascript is going to represent.

Comment: I want a same instruction like scene.getStylesheets().add(Login.class.getResource("login.css").toExternalForm());  but for loading login.js file script

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems the only way is making the fxml file because it isn't implemented to be able executing a .js file from the .java class. The solution code:

file ***Login.java***:

```
package login;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root;
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bienvenido a JavaFX");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

file ***login.fxml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?language javascript?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" styleClass="root">
    <fx:script source="login.js"/>
    <padding>
        <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25"/>
    </padding>
    <Text id="welcome-text" text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>
    <Label text="User Name:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Label text="Password:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <PasswordField id="passwordField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
        <Button text="Sign In" onAction="handleSubmitButtonAction(event);"/>
    </HBox>
    <Text fx:id="actiontarget" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@login.css" />
    </stylesheets>
</GridPane>
```

***Please, note that you only need fx:id when you use the id for a javascript code, otherwise you only need id***

file ***login.js***:

```
function handleSubmitButtonAction() {
    actiontarget.setText("Calling the JavaScript");
}
```

file ***login.css***:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 0.750em;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-text-fill: #333333;
}
.label, #actiontarget {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#welcome-text {
    -fx-font-size: 2.0em;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
    -fx-fill: #818181;
    -fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 6, 0.0, 0, 2);
}
#actiontarget {
    -fx-fill: firebrick;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Narrow";
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#61a2b1, #2A5058);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
    -fx-transition: all 2s linear;
}
.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#2A5058, #61a2b1);
}
```

That's all.